# Spreadsheet published web HTML can't be accessed in Mobile using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this Apps Script wherein I publish each spreadsheet to web (pubHTML) and get the link of it. However, upon testing, the link works via web. I tried also sending the link to my colleague and he was able to access it. But when we tried to open it via mobile, it says that I don't have a permission with the file.

Is it safe to assume that published to web spreadsheets doesn't work on mobile phones if we try to access it?

Thanks!

Comment: No. It isn't safe to assume that. Could you provide the published URL?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/pwc.com/spreadsheets/d/1Etpi5-PPAfbS3lWlGlwDvvL2ZPOxXc3dxWcdTcvtqoA/pubhtml

can you check this one?

Comment: I just get a pwc login page.